# Why this applet doesn't load on IE?

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

I am having trouble with an applet that doesn't loads on IE but does on any other browser.

Here is the problem I see:

[image]

Do you have any idea of how I can fix that problem?
If you want to test, you can try to connect to https://secure.postbox.lu/en/user/luxtrust/login/ and click on SMARTCARD.

The very strange thing is that the same applet loads with exactly the same code on the registration page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resizing the div ?

Comment: The problem was actually something like that. I added a div with a padding around the applet and that fixed it. I hate IE7.